# Replacing strings in vector: Every instance replaced by previous found instance

Tags: r, string, design-patterns, text, replace

I'm working with a lot of text files I have loaded into R and I'm trying to replace every instance (or tag) of `</SPEAKER>` with a certain string found earlier in the text file.

Example:
`"<BOB> Lots of text here </SPEAKER> <HARRY> More text here by a different speaker </SPEAKER>"`

I'd like to replace every instance of `"</SPEAKER>"` with the name of, say `"<BOB>"` and `"<HARRY>"` based on the NAME that has been found earlier, so I'd get this at the end:

`"<BOB> Lots of text here </BOB> <HARRY> More text here by a different speaker </HARRY>"`

I was thinking of looping through the vector text but as I only have limited experience with R, I wouldn't know how to tackle this.

If anyone has any suggestions for how to do this, possibly even outside of R using Notepad++ or another text/tag editor, I'd most appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match

- `<`,
- word characters (capturing them in capture group 1),
- `>`,
- the shortest string (capturing it in capture group 2) until
- `</SPEAKER>`

and then replace that with the

- `<`,
- capture group 1,
- `>`,
- capture group 2 and
- `</` followed by
- capture group 1 and
- `>`

This gives

```
x <- "<BOB> Lots of text here </SPEAKER> <HARRY> More text here by a different speaker </SPEAKER>"

gsub("<(\\w+)>(.*?)</SPEAKER>", "<\\1>\\2</\\1>", x)
## [1] "<BOB> Lots of text here </BOB> <HARRY> More text here by a different speaker </HARRY>"
```